# Group by on substring in a cell

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with column name message and this column contains the values in a fixed format like below.

Format:-

```
QU FRASELH  .CPHBOSK LH/050840  COR MVT
```

What i need is to count no of messages based on group by on 2nd substring (e.g FRASELH in above case)

```
SELECT COUNT(*), ORIGIN_QUEUE
FROM info
where TIME_STAMP >='2016-10-05 00:00:00'and TIME_STAMP<= '2016-10-06 00:00:00'
group by (????)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add more sample data, and the expected result.

Comment: You should specify on what DBMS are you running (Oracle, MySQL, ...) and also what does "fixed format" mean in your case? Which values are fixed in the example? Depending on that the solution will be constructed.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name   db is sql server.

Comment: @EmilHolub  fixed format means values in each cell for message column are having same format.
for example one cell has 4 values (first substring has 2 character _space_2nd substring has 6 character_space and so on).now this format is fixed for all cells under message column.

Answer (score 0):

> @EmilHolub fixed format means values in each cell for message column are having same format. for example one cell has 4 values (first substring has 2 character _space_2nd substring has 6 character_space and so on).now this format is fixed for all cells under message column.

Given that it should be sufficient to do:

```
SELECT substr(ORIGIN_QUEUE,4,6) COUNT(*), 
FROM info
where TIME_STAMP >='2016-10-05 00:00:00'and TIME_STAMP<= '2016-10-06 00:00:00'
group by substr(ORIGIN_QUEUE,4,6)
```

It will group your values based on the 4th to 9th character in the ORIGIN_QUEUE string.

Comment: thanks you. It worked(just it should be substring instead of substr).

Comment: Oh sorry, I work mainly with Oracle databases, I am not sure about all the differences in the code language. Glad it helped.